# Telegram chatbot How to make the telegram chatbot recognize a message sent to a group without the "/" command

Tags: javascript, java, json, telegram, chatbot

How to make the telegram chatbot recognize a message sent to a group without the "/" command

Good morning everyone, through the link
https://api.telegram.org/bot***************************/getupdates

I was able to track the status of messages sent to the telegram chatbot, but when I send a simple message to a group this status is not updated with the message, it is only updated when I enter some command /test for example

Do you know if it is possible to identify some text without being in a registered command? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) in your bot should fix this problem.
With activated privacy mode (which is default), your bot will only see messages especially meant for it.

You can disable it by chatting with @botFather and sending /setprivacy